# Linux + git: user's profile set git command tools

Tags: linux, github, command-line, bash

I'm using GitHub for my project.
There are a few bash scripts there. All of them contains:

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
```

Some of my team members can't run these scripts because they don't have `git command line tools` installed, I think so. Mentioned above lines raises an error.

So, I want to add `git command line tools` automatically for their user's profile.

I hope that adding something similar to:

```
echo "source <path_to_git_prompt>" > /etc/profile
```

should fix this issue, but there are a lot of things that I don't like in this approach:

1. It looks insecure for me (User's profile will be patched by some specific data)
2. I'll need to find `git_prompt` and other `git command line tools` in user's system which is not OK for me, because some of them uses Mint, somebody - Ubuntu, somebody - OS X, etc.

Well, how it may be managed? Is there better ways for adding there tools or maybe install them in some git hooks or so on?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski, `Illegal option -o pipefail`

Comment: Please show `head -n1 script.sh` for failing script.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski, `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Please add following line imediately after the first one: `type set;/bin/bash --version; exit 0` and run the script again on the machine it fails with this `Illegal option` message. Please paste the output.

Comment: @ArturFH, for now I can't access for these machines. I'll write you back in a few hours.